# Overflow width phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to generate a listing.

The problem is that the text overflows the width of the cell B.

How do I place a fixed width and length automatic, so that it does not overflow ?

Attachment:

[image]

Code:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


$objPHPExcel->
    getProperties()
        ->setCreator("TEDnologia.com")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("TEDnologia.com")
        ->setTitle("Exportar Excel con PHP")
        ->setSubject("Documento de prueba")
        ->setDescription("Documento generado con PHPExcel")
        ->setKeywords("usuarios phpexcel")
        ->setCategory("reportes");


$query = mysql_query('select * from articulos');


                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Nombre')
                                ->setCellValue('B1', 'E-mail')
                                ->setCellValue('C1', 'E-mail')
                                ;
                $i=2;

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

                    $xx = "A".$i;
                    $xxx = "B".$i;

                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(10);

                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                                ->setCellValue($xx, $row["cod"])
                                ->setCellValue($xxx, $row["descripcion"]);


                                ;


                    $xxxx = "C".$i;

                    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                    $objDrawing->setName('Logo');
                    $objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
                    $objDrawing->setPath('archivos/articulos/'.$row["imagen"].'');
                    $objDrawing->setCoordinates($xxxx);
                    $objDrawing->setHeight(36);
                    $objDrawing->setWidth(36);
                    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

                $i++;

                }







$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Usuarios');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Think how you would do it in MS Excel itself first, then look for an equivalent method in PHPExcel

Comment: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/634377-prevent-cell-overflow.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```